# How do I know that n^(0.1) = w[ (log n)^10 ] with regard to algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, limit, complexity-theory

assume w = little omega

- one algorithm takes n^(0.1) steps to complete a task
- another algorithm takes (log n)^10 to complete the task

The question asked is whether n^(0.1) = w((log n)^10) is true. I got the answer wrong and said false. However, I'm not sure why I got it wrong if, graphically, (log n)^10 appears to dominate n^(0.1) even at n values in the trillions.

**What I have tried**:

I have tried taking the limit of f(x)/g(x) to see if it goes to infinity. However, after a round of L'Hopital's rule it seems like this approach would be a very involved process.

I have also tried simply graphically assessing whether n^(0.1) grows faster than (log n)^10. And perhaps this is the source of my confusion. My professor said that in the case of logs vs polynomials, that any polynomial always dominates the log. However, I have tried graphing these functions against each other and even at n = 9999999, (log n)^10 seems to clearly dominate n^(0.1).

Am I missing something here? Will n^0.1 dominate (log n)^10 at some point?

Note: I should have clarified that this is all in relation to big O notation and algorithm complexity. Where n^(0.1) and (log n)^10 represent the steps that a given algorithm takes to perform a task. I've added some description to the question which will hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: Is this a programming-related question? Or is it maths?

Comment: n^{0.1} is not a polynomial, hence won't necessarily follow the properties that your professor talks about. You can disprove your claim by taking derivatives of both and comparing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a mathematical proof and not programming.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I suppose my question is related to programming in the sense that it is asking about algorithm analysis. But if this is the wrong place for that, I apologize, I can try posting this somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the base of the log, lets make it a constant B.

Now the easiest way is to prove what you want it to let let n = B<sup>10m</sup>

Then n<sup>0.1</sup> / (log<sub>B</sub> n)<sup>10</sup> = B<sup>m</sup> / (10m)<sup>10</sup>

Now we're comparing a simple exponential to a simple polynomial, and we can prove if necessary that the exponential will dominate...  though *n* will get quite large before it does.

For instance if we find *m* such that 2<sup>m</sup> = (10m)<sup>10</sup>, we get m = 100 or so, so n = 2<sup>1000</sup>.